# How to assign value to a new variable based on another variabe and logical conditions in R?

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R.
Here is the data frame i have:

```
df <- data.frame(Component = c("sctl", "sctL", "sctL", "chap", "chap", "chap", "sctL", "sctL", "sctL", "chap", "chap", "chap"),
                  Frequency = c(2, 4, 4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 0, 1, 3),
                  Genus_strain = c("P_A", "P_B", "P_C", "P_A", "P_B", "P_C", "B_A", "B_B", "B_C", "B_A", "B_B", "B_C"))
```

I want to produce a data frame like this:

```
df1 <-  data.frame(Component = c("sctl", "sctL", "sctL", "chap", "chap", "chap", "sctL", "sctL", "sctL", "chap", "chap", "chap"),
                        Frequency = c(2, 4, 4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 0, 1, 3),
                        Genus_strain = c("P_A", "P_B", "P_C", "P_A", "P_B", "P_C", "B_A", "B_B", "B_C", "B_A", "B_B", "B_C"),
                        Group = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"))
```

As you can see, I want to add a column named Group which will contain values assigned on the basis of Frequency values associated with "chap" Component. The actual set of data is pretty large so, I have to apply the following logical statements here:

"a" is assigned when Frequency of chap = 0

"b" is assigned when Frequency of chap = 1

"c" is assigned when Frequency of chap > 1

To complicate things, I need to assign the same leters to rows displaying the same Genus_strain value. A row containing "sctL" in Component column and "P_A" in Genus_strain column must have the same value "a" assigned in Group column as row with "chap" in Component and "P_A" in Genus_strain.

I have attempted grouping but with miserable effect:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Genus_strain) %>% 
  mutate(df$Groupgroup[df$Frequency == 0] <- "A")
```

I have found similar questions, but have been unable to apply any of the sollutions suggested therein.
Any help you can provide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the number of chap samples is equal to the number of sctL samples, the following should likely work.

```
# Apply the first condition for the chap samples
df$Group <- ifelse(df$Component == "chap" & df$Frequency == 0, "a", 
              ifelse(df$Component == "chap" & df$Frequency == 1, "b", 
                ifelse(df$Component == "chap" & df$Frequency > 1, "c",NA)))

# Split them into two dataframes 
df.chap <- df[df$Component == 'chap',]
df.sctL <- df[df$Component == 'sctL',]

# Order them based on the Genus column
df.chap <- df.chap[order(df.chap$Genus_strain),]
df.sctL <- df.sctL[order(df.sctL$Genus_strain),]

# Now that they have the same ordering, just copy the Genus column
df.sctL$Group <- df.chap$Group

# Bind them
dff <- rbind(df.chap, df.sctL)
```